# Optimal tracks/treads for Desert based tank

Tags: science-based, weapons, vehicles

This questions sounds fairly simple but i just want to be sure.
Imagine if you have an army who's main force comprises Tanks and who have to operate mainly in a desert (think the Great Sand Sea area of the Sahara) area.
These tanks need to be able to go as fast as possible even over those loose sand dunes/mounds, so i figured they need good traction.

Would it be advantageous to give them extra broad tracks or even multiple tracks (like the American T28 Super Heavy Tank)?

Type of ''Stereotypical'' desert i have in mind:
[image]

Comment: Most of the Sahara is stony, not sandy. Actually most of the area of most deserts is stony, not sandy. And there are quite a few very rugged mountains in the Sahara, where any kind of tank would find itself in trouble.

Comment: How easily do you want your tanks to turn corners?

Comment: Define ''easy''

Comment: Why would anybody fight a battle in the place shown in the picture? There is nothing to defend; there is nothing to take; it's not a practicable trade route which could be cut off. Remember that for a battle to take place one side must want to take the field, and the other must want to hold the field. If those conditions are not *both* fulfilled then no battle will ensue.

Comment: @Justin, I think most tanks can control the tank treads separately making them able to turn on the spot by having the treads rotate in opposite directions.

Comment: @AlexP, I think a lot of the middle east is desert and there has been a lot of fighting there. Armies usually don't fight for the pretty landscape but for the resources or the strategic value. (Or sadly sometimes faith)

Comment: @D.J.Klomp: Who fought whom in the dunes? Most of the fighting was to take or to defend cities, lines of communication, pipelines, etc. Not in the dunes.

Comment: @D.J. Klomp Tracked skid steering works very well on flat solid surfaces. The traction between the tread and surface is great enough to provide the counter-push between the tread directions that is needed, and the flat surface reduced the lateral friction to allow sideways movement. On very loose, deep sand, all that happens is the sand sprays out behind each tread and the vehicle just digs a deep hole. There is not enough traction in the sand to overcome the sideways resistance. A vehicle with all wheels independently swiveled can make the maneuver on any surface.

Comment: @Justin, Thanks for the clarification, already thought I was missing something. I was thinking whether the mars rover would be a good example for running on sand. Presumably that is why they use wheels and not treads?

Comment: @D.J.Klomp  they use wheels instead of tread because every ounce counts in space flight and treads are heavier than wheels.

Comment: @D.J. Klomp The ability to independently power and rotate each wheel is a major consideration in the design of these rovers, since there is no predicting what kind of surface they will traverse, and the nature of the obstacles they need to avoid. Another advantage of independent wheels with independent suspension is that it is possible to keep the vehicle body completely horizontal on any slope.  Perhaps the ultimate solution https://www.thedrive.com/the-war-zone/21723/darpas-amazing-reconfigurable-wheel-tracks-go-from-wheel-to-track-in-two-seconds-flat

Answer (score 3):

Tanks handle the desert just fine.

[image]

If you want a tank custom tailored for dune deserts you need 4 things.

1. Bigger cooling system, assuming it is a hot desert, if it is going to operating in hot conditions all the time you want to put more effort into making the cooling system powerful and robust.
2. Wide deep tread to really bite into the loose sand, overdo this however and they will have problems on normal ground.
3. Better air filtration, because otherwise your engine is going to be sucking up a lot of sand.
4. Very good navigation, one of the biggest problems of dune fields is they are very difficult to navigate, dune move constantly and cut off line of sight so getting lost is incredibly easy. this goes double for a tank which has a limited field of view.